# preg_match doesn't works as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working on some data loaded from an Excel file using PHPExcel. Everything is working fine with every fields but I'm having some troubles with a field which should contain a pattern.

The pattern is

```
(([0-2]?[0-9]\:[0-5]?[0-9]\:([0-5]?[0-9])\/([0-2]?[0-9]\:[0-5]?[0-9]\:([0-5]?[0-9])))\s?)*
```

that should check for time intervals such as "00:30:45/01:40:12 01:10:34/1:07:12" and so on.

My problem is that preg_match fails to check this pattern against the sting "1:00". If I add a variable to store the matches returns an one element array with the value "".

I check the pattern with an online tool (http://regexpal.com/) and work as expected but for an to me unknown reason, preg_match doesn't.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you show your call to `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`? It appears to work for me: https://ideone.com/t2JlcN

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$string = "00:30:45/01:40:12 01:10:34/1:07:12";

preg_match_all('!((\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:(\d{1,2}))))\s?!', $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

you need to get this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '00:30:45/01:40:12 ',
    1 => '01:10:34/1:07:12',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '00:30:45/01:40:12',
    1 => '01:10:34/1:07:12',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '00:30:45/01:40:12',
    1 => '01:10:34/1:07:12',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '01:40:12',
    1 => '1:07:12',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '12',
    1 => '12',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[demo](http://ideone.com/0HUNUu)**

```
<?php

 $str = '00:30:45/01:40:12 01:10:34/1:07:12/1:00';
 //$str = '1:00';

 $p = '/[0-9]+:[0-9]+(:[0-9]+|)/s';

 preg_match_all($p, $str, $m);

 print_r($m);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 00:30:45
        [1] => 01:40:12
        [2] => 01:10:34
        [3] => 1:07:12
        [4] => 1:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => :45
        [1] => :12
        [2] => :34
        [3] => :12
        [4] => 
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix this up. After taking a break and come again to the code with a clear mind, I noticed the final '*' should by a '+' in order to force to have, at least, one instance of the time interval.

Thank you all for your responses.